# Why are some of my ranges insane?

Tags: raku

I tried parsing a common string depiction of ranges (e.g. `1-9`) into actual ranges (e.g. `1 .. 9`), but often got weird results when including two digit numbers. For example, `1-10` results in the single value `1` instead of a list of ten values and `11-20` gave me four values (`11 10 21 20`), half of which aren't even in the expected numerical range:

```
put get_range_for('1-9');
put get_range_for('1-10');
put get_range_for('11-20');

sub get_range_for ( $string ) {

    my ($start, $stop) = $string.split('-');

    my @values = ($start .. $stop).flat;

    return @values;
}
```

This prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1
11 10 21 20
```

Instead of the expected:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

---

(I figured this out before posting this question, so I have answered below. Feel free to add your own answer if you'd like to elaborate).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is indeed that `.split` returns `Str` rather than `Int`, which the original answer solves.  However, I would rather implement my "get_range_for" like this:

```
sub get_range_for($string) {
    Range.new( |$string.split("-")>>.Int )
}
```

This would return a `Range` object rather than an `Array`.  But for iteration (which is what you most likely would use this for), this wouldn't make any difference.  Also, for larger ranges the other implementation of "get_range_for" could potentially eat a lot of memory because it vivifies the `Range` into an `Array`.  This doesn't matter much for "3-10", but it would for "1-10000000".

Note that this implementation uses `>>.Int` to call the Int method on all values returned from the `.split`, and then slips them as separate parameters with `|` to `Range.new`.  This will then also bomb should the `.split` return 1 value (if it couldn't split) or more than 2 values (if multiple hyphens occurred in the string).

Comment: that does not use nearly enough special characters - how about `&[..](|+<<$string.split('-'))` instead :p

Comment: @Christoph Nice example. Please post that as another answer. Who needs subs when you can simply write `&[..](|+<<$string.split('-'))`?  :)

Answer (score 7):

The result of `split` is a `Str`, so you are accidentally creating a range of strings instead of a range of integers. Try converting `$start` and `$stop` to `Int` before creating the range:

```
put get_range_for('1-9');
put get_range_for('1-10');
put get_range_for('11-20');

sub get_range_for ( $string ) {

    my ($start, $stop) = $string.split('-');

    my @values = ($start.Int .. $stop.Int).flat; # Simply added .Int here

    return @values;
}
```

Giving you what you expect:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: This approach is fine, but for larger ranges could potentially eat a lot of memory because you're vivifying the Range.  I would write this as: `sub get_range_for($string) { Range.new( |$string.split("-")>>.Int ) }`.  This would return the Range object, which you can iterate over *or* store in an array later, should you wish that.  Note that this uses `>>.Int` to call the `Int` method on all values returned from the `.split`, and then slips them as separate parameters with `|` to `Range.new`.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Good call. Sometimes memory can be an issue. Please create an answer and include your solution.